# Services.CreateScope() Missing in Asp.net Core 2.1

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.1

What replaced Services.CreateScope() in 2.1?

I am trying to follow this tutorial but it seems like stuff has changed quite a bit

https://dotnetthoughts.net/seed-database-in-aspnet-core/

Comment: Have you used Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection?

Answer (score 20):

I had the same problem with the ASP.NET Core MVC with Entity Framework Core tutorial, written for .NET Core 2, trying to run it with .NET Core 2.1. It worked fine once I added

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
```

to the problem file, in my case Program.cs.

Answer (score 6):

You should replace this line of code:

```
var host = BuildWebHost(args);
```

with this

```
var host = CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
        var host = CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build();
        using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
        {
            try
            {
                //
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                ///
            }
        }
        host.Run();
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
```